# Child pages not showing as active

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, parent-child

I'm have an issue with a WordPress theme that I am making using Twitter Bootstrap.

I have two menu's, one of which is a Nav_Walker to which that displays correctly and highlights an active post category if selected, however, the next menu is used to display child pages on the parent page and is using code to do it (See Code). It outputs all the child pages correctly but it doesn't trigger active on the child page menu entry that is being looked at therefor I can't set the active menu item to look any differently.

```
<?php
if ($post->post_parent)
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=" . $post->post_parent . "&echo=0");
else
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=" . $post->ID . "&echo=0");
if ($children) {
    ?>  
<?php } ?></pre>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked uppercase">
    <li class="menu-heading"><h6>OVERVIEW</h6></li>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
```

The the code outputs:

`<ul class = "nav nav-tabs nav-stacked uppercase">
            <li class = "menu-heading"><h6>OVERVIEW</h6></li>
            <li class = ""><a href = "mywebsite">SUB PAGE 1</a></li>
            <li class = ""><a href = "mywebsite">SUB PAGE 2</a></li>
            <li class = ""><a href = "mywebsite">SUB PAGE 3</a></li>
        </ul>`

The class for the li remains empty when the page is active.

Does anyone know how I can work around this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you used wp_get_nav_menu_items() function,It's more help full

Comment: I didn't Mayur. I'm fairly new to this. Would that work with child pages?